# How to show a product from a field entry

Tags: plugin-craftcommerce, matrix, products

I'm trying to bring in recommended products for adding to a bigger purchase. I set up a simple matrix but can't seem to figure out how to pull product information. This is what I have so far, it throws no errors, but it also gives nothing.

```
{% for block in product.recommendProduct %}
    {% set i = i + 1 %}
       <div>
           {% set image = block.chooseProduct.mainProductImage.first() %}
            <img src="{{ image.getUrl('productListing') }}">
            <p>{{ block.chooseProduct.title }}</p>
       </div>
{% endfor %}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This should work:

```
{% set image = block.chooseProduct.first().mainProductImage.first() %}
```

Explanation:
your field handle in your product is called `recommendProduct` (matrix) that contains a relation `chooseProduct`. Your `block.chooseProduct` is an object of type `ElementCriteriaModel` so in order to fetch the product you need to call the `first()` method (or something similar). So if you have multiple products in your `chooseProduct` field your code would look like this

```
{% for block in product.recommendProduct %}
{% set i = i + 1 %}
   <div>
       {% for relatedProduct in block.chooseProduct %}
            {% set image = relatedProduct.mainProductImage.first() %}
            <img src="{{ image.getUrl('productListing') }}">
            <p>{{ relatedProduct.title }}</p>
       {% endfor %} 
   </div>
{% endfor %}
```